Displaying consecutive months on QGIS DataPlotly plugin
In the DataPlotly plugin for QGIS, I have the following chart where the X-axis shows dates.

Unfortunately, I cannot change the configuration of the X-axis to display all months (JAN, FEB, MAR, APR) in a trimester format, even though I stretch the chart. This seems to be the only possible representation when I need to identify all months consecutively. The X-axis is fed with daily information, so all days from January to October are included.
